# vertical stacking of text views in expandableListView

Tags: java, android, mobile, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

**Hello fellow devs,**

**I've got an odd requirement that I'd like to share that relates to an expandableListView. I'm going to try and explain via screenshots.**

[image: How it looks Now]

**That's how it looks now, with just two text views showing two values.
The requirement I got is to "push the values up, allowing room to enter two more values below"
I've asked if I can just append the two additional TextViews to the existing linearLayout, but got a strong "No, we do not want that."**

Below is a new screenshot with how I think they want it to look (assume all text is the same font).

[image: How it should look when I'm done]

**Is this even possible? I'm not seeing any way to stack related textviews vertically without adding another child view, which I don't think they will be happy with. Thanks.**

Answer (score 0):

I would get the second text under the first and use spannable to alter the text size, just a taught.
Edit--> And alter the style with html

```
String text = "<font color=#cc0029>Erste Farbe</font> <font color=#ffcc00>zweite Farbe</font>";
```